# How to check if all fields whose names are given in an array are non-null?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a javascript array which contains the name of fields in a record:

```
fields=["size", "Hold","drawn%" ,"expiry"]
```

I need to persorm an operation,if the value in ALL these fields is not null.

I can iterate the array and check a not-null condition on each element.
Is there a better way to handle this; wherein each member of the array has to be evaluated against a particular condition, and return a cumulative true or false.

Comment: you can write a function, which takes array as param,  checks it and returns true only if all elements meet the requirement

Comment: Right, that function already exists, it's called `Array#every`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fields.every(function(name, i) { return record[name] !== null; })
```

will return `true` if every field from `fields` in `record` is not null, and false otherwise.

Comment: For those that have to support IE8 and below, `Array.prototype.every` isn't supported in anything less than IE9. There is, however, a useful polyfill [here on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.prototype.IsNull = function() {
        var arr = this;
        var isNull = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == null) {
                isNull = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return isNull;
    }; 

var fields=["size", "Hold","drawn%" ,"expiry"]; 
var isNull = fields.IsNull();
```